# How do I split a dataset into training and test sets by using a split indicator?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have my dataset which I'm trying to split into my training and test sets. However, I have a column within the dataset that I want to use to tell the program if I want an entity in the data to be placed into the training set or into the test set.

Let's say this column is called 'split', and its two options are 'train' and 'test'.

How do I split the data by having all items with a value of 'train' under the 'split' column go into my training set, and all items with a value of 'test' go into my testing set?

Comment: Let's say your whole dataset is `df` and it has `split` column: `train = df[df['split'] == 'train']` and `test = df[df['split'] == 'test']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
train_df = df[df['split']=="train"]

test_df = df[df['split']=="test"]
```